# How does Angular 2 know where to import things from?

Tags: angular

I was looking at Angular 2 Quickstart and I noticed these lines at the top of the angular files

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
```

My question is, how does the browser know where to find `angular2/platform/browser` and `./app.component`? These are not the correct paths in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

When you import the `angular2.dev.js`, a set of modules is registered explicitly using `System.register('module-name', ...`.

For your application TypeScript file, it's a bit different. When compiling them with the TypeScript compiler, an anonymous module is defined within the corresponding JS file. This means that you need to configure SystemJS to link a module name with the JS file.

With the following configuration, it will deduce that modules that starts with `app` must be loaded from an URL. For example, `import {...} from 'app/main';` will corresponds to `http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`.

```
System.config({
  packages: {      
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `an anonymous module is defined within the corresponding JS file`? What are you referring to?

Comment: An anonymous module is a JS file that uses System.register but without the module name as first parameter. This is what the typescript compiler generates by default when systemjs is configured as module manager.